# How can I re allocate my output buffer for zlib's inflate function?

Tags: c++, zlib

I'm trying to inflate into a buffer in memory something that I previously deflated with deflate().

The issue is that I seemingly cannot know when to resize the output buffer with each call to inflate().

The Zlib examples do not have this problem because they simply assume the inflated data will not overrun their buffer.

Anyone solved this issue?

Comment: You generally call `inflate` in a loop with a fixed-size buffer, until the call to `inflate` returns an error.

Comment: Adding to Jonathan's comment, or until `inflate()` returns **Z_STREAM_END**. Also note for single-shot decompression to work reliably, from the zlib docs, *"After compression, total_in holds the total size of the uncompressed data and may be saved for use in the decompressor (particularly if the decompressor wants to decompress everything in a single step)."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What zlib examples are you referring to?  The ones I know of make no such assumption.  You tell `inflate()` how much space is in your output buffer, `avail_out`, and it will only write that much decompressed data.  The buffer is not overrun.  You then do whatever you need to do with that data, and call `inflate()` again, reusing the same buffer by resetting `next_in` and `avail_in`.

You should read [this heavily annotated example](http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html) of how to use zlib.

Do you want to read it all into a single buffer using, as it seems you are implying, `realloc()`?  In that case, you simply see that `avail_out` has gone to zero, reallocate the buffer, update `avail_out` (and `next_out` since the `realloc()` may have moved the buffer) and call `inflate()` again.

Comment: I was completely misunderstanding avail_out. Your explanation here is far easier to understand than the documentation. Thanks.